# Vertices Move Around With Jerking Motion

Tags: vertices

I pressed <kbd>G</kbd> and tried to move vertices but they move with these drastic jerking motion. How do I freely move this around?

[Click here to see what I'm talking about](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00EoYEqv3BI&feature=youtu.be)

Thanks a billion. I'm totally new at this and I have no idea what's happening!

Comment: it is very small on the video, but it seems you have a snapping option : the little magnet on the bottom right part of the 3D view. You may deactivate it.